# HTML 5 : Text box getting highlighted

Tags: javascript, android, css, html

Android : jquery mobile textbox overlap on fixed header while scrolling

While user click on any text box and start scrolling, the focused text box overlap(showing above) the fixed header.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk6nzeeqrx68uai/Screenshot_2013-10-01-10-19-39-2.png

Is there any idea which prevents the textbox to get highlighted when user click on that one.

Img : https://www.dropbox.com/s/43nee5bw4x9grzk/Screenshot_2013-10-01-13-37-11-1.png

I want the second textbox also to be the same as first one after clicking.

Thanks
Razz

Comment: what are you using? is it hybrid application or native android app?

Comment: yes it is a hybrid application

Comment: use user-scalable=no" in meta tag in header of html

Answer (score 1):

Use `Selector.xml` file inyour drawable and then use two different background images. One is hover image another one is normal image.

Ex :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_Bg" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_Bg" android:state_focused="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_Bg"></item>

</selector>
```

In your layout set like this.

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstname_edt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/Selector"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Hybrid application (HTML5,JS) use user-scalable=no" in meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><input type="text"  class="textbox" id="beneficiary_name" name="beneficiary_name" value="" onkeypress="validateBenNameAddress(event)" maxlength="35" />

Comment: can i write like that ?

Comment: No you need to add this meta tag in header part of .html page

Comment: like... 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>your app title</title>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: then I think there is problem with the css written for text box